# Python - How to identify un-commented if statements lines in cpp file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm writing a `Python` code that suppose to identify **un-commented** `if statement` lines read from a cpp file. I just need to be able to tell whether a line contains an if statement.

So far I have this poor attempt:

```
import re
r = re.compile(".*if.*(.*).*")

line1 = "if  ( true )"          # should match
line2= "// if(true)"            # should NOT match
line3= "/* if(true) */"         # should NOT match

print r.search(line1) # match
print r.search(line2) # match
print r.search(line3) # match
```

My problem is that `line2` & `line3` are matched in my faulty regexp. Any ideas?

#### Note

Recognizing `if statement` in multi-line comment is irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead assertion.

```
re.search(r'^(?!/[/*]).*?\bif\s*\(.*?\).*', string)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF9jP6/1)

OR

Add `\s*` at the start inside the negative lookahead if necessary.

```
^(?!\s*/[/*]).*?\bif\s*\(.*?\).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF9jP6/2)

**Update:**

This won't allow `else` string before `if`

```
^(?!\s*/[/*])(?:(?!\belse\b).)*\bif\s*\(.*?\).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF9jP6/3)

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> line1 = "if  ( true )"
>>> line2= "// if(true)"
>>> line3= "/* if(true) */"
>>> r = re.compile(r'^(?!/[/*]).*?if.*?\(.*?\).*')
>>> r.search(line1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='if  ( true )'>
>>> r.search(line2)
>>> r.search(line3)
>>>
```

Comment: You have false positive in this line `   //  specific functionallity ()`

Comment: Seems like the edit you made, `^(?!\s*/[/*]).*?if.*?\(.*?\).*`, solved it.

Comment: But still false positive in `else if (true)`. I'll this requirement to the question.

Comment: then this `^(?!\s*/[/*])(?:(?!\belse\b).)*if.*?\(.*?\).*` https://regex101.com/r/rF9jP6/3

Comment: Anyother false positives?

Comment: Yes. function definition: `virtual void OnBeforeifStatement();`

Comment: did you want to match the above statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67795/discussion-between-idanshmu-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!\/\/|\/\*.*\*\/$).*if.*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/6

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(?!\/\/|\/\*.*\*\/$).*if.*', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "\nif ( true ) # should match\n// if(true) # should NOT match\n/* if(true) */"

re.findall(p, test_str)


NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if                       'if'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```